# WPF Canvas not have access to GetLeft method (static method)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a canvas defined in UserControl and I want to access `GetLeft` method which is static. The problem is that this method requires static field... I tried to make a static constructor, but didn't helped... Any solution? I attached the code below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DiagramDesigner.Resources.DesignerCanvas"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="CanvasX" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Code:

```
CanvasX.GetLeft(new DesignerItem());
```

Error:

> Cannot acces static method 'GetLeft' in non static context

Answer (score 2):

To access static members you should specify the declaring `Type` instead a variable.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> The static member is callable on a class even when no instance of the class has been created. The static member is always accessed by the class name, not the instance name.

So the correct syntax is:

```
double left = Canvas.GetLeft(designedItem);
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is `Canvas.GetLeft( designerItem )`

GetLeft is a static method you pass a child element into - this method does not care which particular canvas the child is contained in.